# How to achieve "Data Streaming" in Java - Database interaction?

Tags: java, database

Context:

1. I have a java based application, lets say AppA
2. It queries a database, let's say DataD
3. It works on that data, does some magic and passes it on to another application, say AppB

Issue:

1. The amount of data in DataD is quite large.
2. My AppA is not really equipped to handle all that data at one go.
3. My AppB is also not really interested in getting all the data at one go.

Solution:

1. I want to query data from DataD, but only in bunches of say 10,000 (configurable) at a time.
2. I will work on that batch in AppA, pass it onto the AppB and then do another query on DataD.
3. I will have to tell DataD, how many records I have already read, and ask it to give the next 10,000. So somehow, my AppA needs to keep a track of the last read number and have a clever way of querying DataD effectively for a range of data.
4. My DataD does not have any way of keeping count (or maintaining flag) of what it had already sent back. It is a database and it is not possible to slap any SOA / REST intelligence on top of it either. So, my AppA will have to be intelligent enough to do the query for specific range.

Question:

1. Without resorting to too much jugglery in core java, is it somehow possible to use any framework to achieve this - what I like to call - "data streaming"? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds way to complicated, I suggest you try to make it as simple as possible.

I would have AppA perform the query and process each row as it gets it and write the derived data to a Socket which AppB is listening to.  Unless you know this causes a performance problem, I wouldn't make it any more complicated.

Comment: I am afraid that is not going to work. As I said, my AppA is not equipped to handle all the data of DataD at one go. It just does not have that much memory.

Comment: As I stated; AppA only needs to `process each row as it gets it`  I assume AppA can process one whole row at least.

Comment: Yes. It definitely can process one row at a time. Actually even 10,000 would be alright. But I guess I am missing the point. As I understand, if I were to create a JDBC connection to DataD and run a query, I will get all the records in memory at one go. I am not going to get one row at a time. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can control the prefetch size for JDBC but it is usually something sensible and quite small, e.g. 10. http://triton.towson.edu/~schmitt/java/jdbc/doc/jdbcoci7.htm#423113

Comment: Ah, that sounds good. Let me check it out tomorrow and I will report back.